# Error: fatal: --local can only be used inside a git repository

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-lfs

Today when I run the github actions, shows error like this:

```
Error: fatal: --local can only be used inside a git repository
```

this is the full log about the actions log:

```
Run actions/checkout@v3
Syncing repository: RedDwarfTech/cv_render
Getting Git version info
Temporarily overriding HOME='/home/runner/work/_temp/2abd7da7-7754-4217-b5db-2984399b003e' before making global git config changes
Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /home/runner/work/cv_render/cv_render
/usr/bin/git config --local --get remote.origin.url
Error: fatal: --local can only be used inside a git repository
Deleting the contents of '/home/runner/work/cv_render/cv_render'
Initializing the repository
Disabling automatic garbage collection
Setting up auth
Fetching the repository
Determining the checkout info
Checking out the ref
/usr/bin/git log -1 --format='%H'
'28106b95ce29effd8f28340d7e6cbba265a04e71'
```

and this is my github actions define:

```
- name: Checkout source
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    lfs: false
```

why did this issue happen? what should I do to fixed this issue? This is the full github actions look liks:

```
name: cv-render-k8s-pro

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Cache
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        key: lfs-cache
        path: .git/lfs
        restore-keys: |
          - lfs-cache

    - name: Checkout source
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        lfs: false
        
    - name: Install git-lfs
      run: |
        curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
        sudo apt-get install git-lfs

    - name: Set Git LFS default remote URL
      run: |
        git remote set-url origin https://${{ secrets.LFS_USER_NAME }}:${{ secrets.LFS_PASSWORD }}@codeup.aliyun.com/6299c42d487c500c27f5f963/cv_render.git
        git config --global credential.helper store
        git config --global user.email "jiangtingqiang@gmail.com"
        git config --global user.name "jiangchaoquan123456"

    - name: Initialize Git LFS
      run: |
        git lfs install

    - name: Pull LFS files
      run: |
        git lfs pull

    - name: Set up QEMU
      uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

    - name: Login to Docker Hub
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
        registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
        username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}

    - name: Build and push
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
      with:
        context: .
        file: Dockerfile
        push: true
        tags: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}/reddwarf-pro/cv-render:${{ github.sha }} 

    - name: deploy to cluster
      uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
      with: 
        config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
        command: set image --record deployment/cv-render-service cv-render-service=${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}/reddwarf-pro/cv-render:${{ github.sha }} -n reddwarf-pro

    - name: verify deployment
      uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
      with:
        config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
        version: v1.21.0
        command: rollout status deployment/cv-render-service -n reddwarf-pro
```

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve] with a complete actions workflow in order to reproduce the issue? Are you using `actions/checkout` multiple times in the same job? Are you maybe overriding paths somewhere?

Comment: If this worked before, try pinning to an older version of `actions/checkout` by using `actions/checkout@v3.5.3`, you've pinned to v3, so you'll be upgraded to latest automatically. If that fixes the issue, file a bug here: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues

Comment: You may want to put the LFS Cache restore **after** the checkout task. I'm guessing the checkout task balks because it finds a `.git` folder, but that's actually not a valid git repo, as it only contains the lfs files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `actions/checkout` task in the most default setup . It looks like you're trying to use LFS storage from a different storage provider than GitHub.

Your `actions/cache`, if successful, will create a `.git/lfs` folder in the runners working directory. That `.git` folder isn't a proper git repo, it's missing all kinds of stuff, but it will trigger a number of different routines in the runner as it needs to check whether the repo is usable for this workflow run or needs to be cleaned up. That code fails.

I'm guessing you can work around the issue by placing the `actions/checkout` step before the `action/cache` step. That way there is no `.git` folder and the `actions/checkout` step will act as normal on a hosted runner. The `actions/cache` step can then restore the LFS cache in the `.git` folder and after that you can change the LFS configuration to sync the rest of the files if needed.

Answer (score -1):

The error is telling you that you want to do something locally in a directory that's not a git repository. You will need to find out which is the directory where this command is being executed. Possibilities:

- your command may be executed at the wrong directory, in which case you will need something like `cd /the/path/to/the/correct/directory` before your command, or pass the location where the git command is to be executed, like `git -C /the/path/to/the/correct/directory <somecommand>`
- your command may be executed at the correct directory, which is not properly initialized as a git repository, in which case you may want to run `git init` to initialize, or review other steps and find out whether they do something like the removal of the `.git` folder

The symptom of your issue is that

```
git config --local <whatever>
```

will error out in the way you have mentioned if it's not executed either at the correct location or while specifying the correct location, like

```
git -C <somepath> config --local <whatever>
```

Comment: I am happy to improve upon this answer if those who down-voted it would elaborate on what needs improvement.

Comment: Your answer explains when such an error might occur, but given the command runs in the code of GitHub in a CI/CD tool it's not really helpful. In the end none of the potential symptoms you mentioned are correct. That's why I downvoted.

Comment: @jessehouwing thanks for the comment, it's incredibly rare to get reasons for downvotes, appreciated. Indeed, I focused on the git error and described the reasons for it. Admittedly, while I'm very confident with git in general, I am not quite as experienced with GitHub CI/CD and I treated this as a git problem. Your criticism might be correct on this one, I do not know yet. I will try to find out what the exact truth is and, if I manage to find it out, then I will get back to this answer and remove/improve upon it. Thanks again!